# How can I compute simple examples of the associated vector bundle to a coherent sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Given a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{E} \in \text{Coh}(X)$ over a scheme there is a way to associate a relatively affine scheme over $X$. This is done by constructing the $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebra
$$
\text{Sym}^\bullet(\mathcal{E}) = \mathcal{O}_X \oplus \mathcal{E} \oplus \text{Sym}^2(\mathcal{E})\oplus \text{Sym}^3(\mathcal{E})\oplus \cdots
$$
and then taking relative spec
$$
\mathbb{V}(\mathcal{E}) = \underline{\text{Spec}}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\text{Sym}^\bullet(\mathcal{E}))
$$
I am having trouble figuring how to compute basic examples of this, so

**how can I compute $\mathbb{V}(\mathcal{E})$ in simple cases?**

such as

1. $\mathcal{O}(k)$ over $\mathbb{P}^n$
2. $\mathcal{O}(k)\oplus \mathcal{O}(l)$ over the same space

I know that I can use these computations to find the same associated vector bundles to some projective variety using pullbacks.

---

As per Ben's suggestion, I'll look at $\mathbb{P}^1$. Since we have the embedding
$$
\mathcal{O}(-1) \xrightarrow{\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}} \mathcal{O}\oplus\mathcal{O}
$$
I expect this to be the sub-variety of $\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{P}^1}$ defined by the equation
$$
\frac{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}[a,b]}{(ya - xb)}
$$
where $\mathbb{P}^1 = \text{Proj}(\mathbb{C}[x,y])$. In general, this should be given by all of the linear relations cutting out a line over each point of $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: First, you write $E^{\otimes 2}$ above, which is not correct, it should be $S^2 E$. Second, what exactly do you mean by `compute' in your question? What information do you want to extract other than saying it is the variety associated to the symmetric algebra?

Comment: I want to compute a presentation of the vector bundle using relative spec. For example, $\underline{\text{Spec}}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{O}_X[y_1,y_2]) = \mathbb{A}^2_{X}$.

Comment: Also, $\underline{\text{Spec}}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\text{Sym}^\bullet(\mathcal{O}_X\oplus\mathcal{O}_X)) = \mathbb{A}^2_X$

Comment: I suggest that you try these for $n=1$ and already see that they are not so pleasant to write down (though it can be). For trivial bundles like $\mathcal{O}_X^n$, these are of course easy.

Comment: @Mohan I wonder if macaulay2 can compute this...

Comment: For $k\geq 0$, theoretically it can be written down, but what do you wish to understand from such a complicated description in general?

Comment: @Mohan This is part of the construction of virtual fundamental classes. You have to take the cone of a coherent sheaf, which is similar to the question.

Comment: A simple example of a cone is $(xy,xz) \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]=R$, then $\text{Sym}(I/I^2) \cong R[a,b]/(az - by)$

Comment: A nice exercise is to find the equations defining the total space of the tautological sub-bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-1)\subset\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}^{n+1}$ as the sub-scheme of the trivial bundle $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\cong \mathbb A^{n+1}\times\mathbb P^n$.

Comment: @Ben Cool! I updated my question to answer your comment. How do I handle the dual situation?